# React - setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, state

I am getting the `setState` error when inside a secondary component using react-router. Can anyone see any issues in my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import './App.css';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: []
    };
    this.setInfo = this.setInfo.bind(this);

    this.setInfo();
  }

  setInfo = () => {
    var info = [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Server Space',
        subtitle: '',
        textContent: ''
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Pi Space',
        subtitle: '',
        textContent: ''
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ info: info });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <Row>
          {this.state.info.map((inf) => {
            return (
              <Col xs={12} md={4} key={inf.id}>
                <Card className="card">
                  <CardTitle title={inf.title} subtitle={inf.subtitle} />
                  <CardText>{inf.textContent}</CardText>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            )
          })}
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

This results in:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Dashboard component.
```

The line in question is `this.setState({ info: info });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not supposed to call `this.setState` in the constructor.
You can set the state directly:

```
var info = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Server Space',
    subtitle: '',
    textContent: ''
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Pi Space',
    subtitle: '',
    textContent: ''
  }
];

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: info
    };
    this.setInfo = this.setInfo.bind(this);
  }

  setInfo = () => {
    this.setState({ info: info });
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused why this wasn't working as I've done this before, but I realised I was using superagent and calling setState in the asynchronous end function

Comment: Thanks for sharing, didn't work for my use case. It is what I have
    constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { data : this.props.cryptos, isLoading : false };
  setInterval(() => {
   this._query(query);
  }, 6000);
 };
 _handleResponse(response) {
  this.setState({ data : response, isLoading : false });
 };
 _query(query) {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true});
   fetch(query)
    .then(response => response.json()).then(json =>  this._handleResponse(json) )  .catch(error => this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        message: 'Error: ' + error
   }));
 };

Comment: I found that I need to clear interval when component is unmount, here is the great article about intervals http://reactnativequickly.com/book/chap07.html

Answer (score 4):

Component `constructor` is called before component is mounted so you can't call `setState` in it (`setState` can be called only on mounted components). The constructor is the right place to initialize state but you should  do it by setting state directly:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var info = [...];
  this.state= {
    info: info
  };
}
```

Please note that outside `constructor` you should never set state directly - `constructor` is the only exception where you can do it.